# GNU Emacs 24: Saving and Restoring Multiple Frames Layout

Tags: emacs

I am using multiple monitors and I am leveraging them when using Emacs by using one main frame where I do all my code (the screen in front of me).

Then, I put a Speedbar frame on my left monitor and a REPL (Cider) frame on my right monitor.

What I want is to find a way to save and restore these frames arrangements, with the buffers that were loaded in them, etc.

I tried multiple packages such as Workgroups and Workgroups2 and read about others. But most, if not all, of them are saving a single frame but with all the major/minor modes and theirs buffers.

I thought that I could do that with Workgroups, but I cannot manage to use it to do just.

Comment: I want three monitors !!!  :)

Comment: @lawlist why stop to three when you can get six? The problem is that the racking is more expensive than the monitors and video cards :D

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs 24.4, you can use Desktop Save Mode to save and restore (almost) the entire frame and window layout of an Emacs session, including their contents.  Just add the following to your `init.el`:

```
(desktop-save-mode)
```

It's only “almost” the entire session, because Desktop Save Mode cannot restore buffers with attached processes, i.e. Cider Repls, for obvious reasons.

For older Emacsen, you are limited to what Workgroups and Workgroups2 provide, i.e. a best-guess restore of a single frame only.  These Emacs versions lack internal API (i.e. framesets) that is required to accurately restore multiple frames, and 3rd party packages only have limited means to work around these shortcomings.

Comment: thanks! I did try the `desktop-save-mode`, but it doesn't seem to save multiple frames (on different monitors), does it?

Comment: @Neoasimov It does restore multiple frames on a single monitor.  I do not know whether it works in multi-monitor setups, for I scarcely use multi-monitors.  But iirc, Emacs is lacking proper multi-monitor support, so you might be out of luck.  It's being worked on, though.  In any case, it's the best that you'll get.  If it breaks, report a bug with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: great, so I may be out of luck. But I will only have to start my stuff manually then. Not big a deal if it cannot be automated. I will re-check later how I could use Workgroups to automate some of it. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried `desktop-save-mode` on OS X using two monitors and three frames. Basically , it seems to work. (It got a bit confused since it didn't save `ns-auto-hide-menu-bar`, but if you ensure that it's set before the desktop is read back in, things should work anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use library [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) then you can create **desktop bookmarks** and use them to switch among Emacs desktops (different desktop files, located anywhere).

If you use Emacs 24.4 or later then your desktop files can include frame-config information, so switching to one restores its frame config as well.  (I cannot speak to how this feature relates to multiple monitors, however.)

Comment: good, I will check that as well. I will re-test, but not sure this works on multi-monitors the way I want it to (I think it was always getting re-created back on the first monitor)